# how to fix this error in drupal 7

Tags: php, filter, drupal-7

Please someone could help me I dont have much experience in drupal Iam making a website and I want to put some filters for users to search for information I am using views_dependent_filters I have a filter with 4 countries I want that when users select a contry another field to be displayed with the cities in this countries I have done this right I think but I got this error, I am running this website at the moment in a local server, this is the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: dependent_exposed_filters in views_dependent_filters_exposed_form_after_build() (line 32 of C:\wamp\www\ukmarketplace\sites\all\modules\views_dependent_filters\views_dependent_filters.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in views_dependent_filters_exposed_form_after_build() (line 32 of C:\wamp\www\ukmarketplace\sites\all\modules\views_dependent_filters\views_dependent_filters.module).
```

and the filter sometimes is ok and sometimes not, I ve updated my website running update.php and nothing, clear the cache and nothing if someone could help me i would appreciate it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue in the modules issue queue: http://drupal.org/node/1441352. Please check the [patch in comment #12](http://drupal.org/files/1441352.views_dependent_filters.exposed-filters-block.patch).